# Set the value in Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to set the value in this field

This is the inpect code:

```
<dnx-textfield label="First / Leading IP Address" placeholder="" name="primaryIpv4Address" hint="" maxwidth="300px" error="" regex="" message="" validator="" regextype="" type="text" validateon="onblur" hinthelper="" inputid="management-DnxTextfield-deploymentModel" errorhelper="" expandable="" showhide="" source="none" errormsg="" maxlength="2000" autocomplete="off" defined="" required="" data-analyticsid="dnx-textfield[name='primaryIpv4Address']" value="" isfocus="">
 <div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"><div class="dnx-shadow form-group floating-label _float    " style="width: 300px;">
   <div id="dnx_inputfield_containermanagement-DnxTextfield-deploymentModel" class="dnx_inputfield_container">
    <input id="management-DnxTextfield-deploymentModel" class="form-control value" type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" data-testid="dnxTextfield-input" maxlength="2000"></div><label class="control-label  " for="management-DnxTextfield-deploymentModel">First / Leading IP Address<span class="required " style="color: red;">*</span></label><small>&nbsp;</small></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</dnx-textfield>
```

where I tried to fill **192.168.1.1** in value=""

```
<dnx-textfield label="First / Leading IP Address" ...
  value="" isfocus="">
```

But didn't work with several trial.

```
- driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@name='primaryIpv4Address' and @label='First / Leading IP Address']").send_keys("192.168.1.1"+Keys.TAB)
- driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='management-DnxTextfield-deploymentModel']").send_keys("192.168.1.1"+Keys.TAB)
- driver.find_element(By.ID, "management-DnxTextfield-deploymentModel").send_keys("192.168.1.1"+Keys.TAB)
- driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-testid='dnxTextfield-input' and @id='management-DnxTextfield-deploymentModel']").send_keys("192.168.1.1"+Keys.TAB)
- driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='management-DnxTextfield-deploymentModel']").send_keys("192.168.1.1"+Keys.TAB)
- driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='management-DnxTextfield-primarySubnetIpv4Address']").send_keys("192.168.1.1"+Keys.TAB)
- driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@name='primaryIpv4Address' and @label='First / Leading IP Address']").send_keys("192.168.1.1"+Keys.TAB)
```

Is there anyone who can help and take a look at this?

Thanks!

Comment: can u confirm the url?

Comment: sorry, can't access from internet.
do you have any idea on my query ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Java code using which you can do it. You need to use java script executor.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter the xpath here"));
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='enter the value here';", element);
```